# Hiding Div in Small Screens without Running Server Side Code

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, responsive-design

I have a page where it will query the list of all users, and displays it in a design based on Cards component. In case screen size is small, I want to list users with all attributes using a different design. I can have two `<div>`s; one for large screens and other for small screen and hide `<div>` using media query (CSS). The question is, will there be any performance disadvantage for this case? I mean, will server side codes inside the div for large screen gets executed when screen is small, even though it is not displayed?

For example, you are browsing this page in large screen.

```
<div class ="show-for-small-only">
//some for loop in php and other code (A)
</div>
<div class ="show-for-small-only">
//some for loop and other php code (B)
</div>
```

Will code section (A) be executed but not displayed? or it will never hit that section? Note that css class "show-for-small/large-only is a media css query to display:none based on screen size.

Comment: Set the default state of the code-heavy <div> to display:none and then set it to display with an @media rule only if the screen is bigger than say...600px for example.

Comment: Why don't you just set it up with ONE div, regardless of screen size, which you then adjust / style differently based on @media-queries? As long as you're gonna display the same list of users regardless, just presented differently?

Comment: I agree with @junkfoodjunkie. You just need to adapt your "card" design with css depending on the size of the screen instead of having 2 different set of cards with the same content displayed differently.

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS media queries, it's way faster that JQuery.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    .show-for-small-only {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

but you should adapt the design of your card depending on viewport size and/or screen orientation instead of loading it twice with 2 different styles like :

```
.title-section {
  position:absolute;
  top:2%;
  left:0%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    .title-section {
        left: auto;
        right: 0%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers that you have been given are both good, yet i'll recommend you to take a look at bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/), with it you can do what you want just by adding a css classes to your divs.

Answer (score -2):

You can try using this http://mobiledetect.net/

```
 <?php  
// Include and instantiate the class.
require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect; ?> 

// Execute only if the device is mobile
<?php if ( $detect->isMobile() ) { ?>
<div class ="show-for-small-only">
//some for loop in php and other code (A)
</div>
<?php } ?>

<div class ="show-for-small-only">
//some for loop and other php code (B)
</div>
```

Or maybe append stuff from the larger display div to the smaller display div if the screen size is small using jquery and style accordingly.

Html

```
<div class ="show-for-small-only" id="mobile">
// append here if mobile
</div>


<div class ="show-for-small-only">
<div id="wrapper">
//some for loop and other php code (B)
</div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
if($(document).width() <= 450){ 
$("#wrapper").appendTo("#mobile");
}
```

Comment: Just use css media queries instead. I've done the same effect in less than 100 characters.

Comment: @bastien well the difference would

Comment: @BastienBastiens well even if you set it to display none, the php code will be executed on the server side meaning double the work..

Comment: instead of having two set of cards, you can change the style of the card depending on the screen size and/or orientation and this is where you save a lot of time

Comment: And what if he wants the two divs to separate or differently placed?

Comment: CSS Flexbox order : <integer> will rearrange them automatically when you specify the order. This is a great doc explaining how it works : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: and what if i want to it to be two separate divs like on dekstop it should be on the side on a post content div and meta content div but on mobile it should after the post div and meta div

Comment: or somewhere else on the page

Comment: And for that i would have to re write the whole css of the page to flex where as i could simply use 3 lines of jQuery and do the job..